# Нейронные сети на стороне клиента

Tags: нейронные-сети, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Добрый день! Есть идея сделать мобильное приложение, в котором будет использоваться нейронная сеть. Сеть будет распознавать текст перед камерой устройства. Есть некоторые вопросы:
1)Насколько большой будет нагрузка? Текст не очень большой, до 20 символов
2)Какую библиотеку использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Шаг 1.

Научиться распознавать символы как вы хотите не на клиенте, а просто так - оффлайн. Это проблема не из простых. Если бы это было просто, капча с буквами просто перестала бы существовать. Однако это не так. Как научитесь, переходите к следующему шагу.

## Шаг 2.

У вас есть архитектура сети, которую вы можете научить читать текст в нужном вам виде. Теперь нужно определиться на каких устройства будет выполняться ваша обученная сеть. Для этих устройств изучить всё способы "посчитать" нейронную сеть. Сейчас это такие варианты, через полгода или год, когда вы решите задачу из первого шага, будут другие. Тогда стоит задать вопрос ещё раз, приложив конкретные требования к размеру сети и т.п.